# Dividing DIVs to Horizontal and Vertically continously

Tags: css, html, split

I need to be able divide each div both horizontal and vertical. My solution works great until I write some content, the cells are not aligned. Here is what I get on my PC, see the top is misalgined, the green part is belower than the black part. [image: sreenshot] Here is the JSFiddle of my solution: http://jsfiddle.net/Q3r73/ what am I doing wrong?

The code I used to split is:

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
}
div{
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-table;
}
.horizontal, .vertical {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.horizontal > div {
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
}
.vertical > div {
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
}
```

**I want it to be flexible, any div should be able to be divided either horizontal or vertical**

Comment: Do you know how to use firebug to see what code relates to what part of the screen image?  If not, now's the time to bone up on that.

Answer (score 1):

check this code maybe will be helpful for you [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q3r73/2/):

```
*{margin:0; padding:0;}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
div {
    display: block;
}
.left{
    height:100%;
    width:50%;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.firstRight, .secondRight{
    height:100%;
    width:25%;
    float:left;
}
.firstRight{background-color:yellow;}
.secondRight{background-color:red;}
.top{
    width:100%;
    height:50%;
    float:left;
    background-color:green;
}
.bottomLeft, .bottomRight{
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    float:left;
}
.bottomLeft{background-color:yellow;}
.bottomRight{background-color:red;}

<div class="left">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="bottomLeft"></div>
    <div class="bottomRight"></div>
</div>
<div class="firstRight"></div>
<div class="secondRight"></div>
```

Comment: This needs setting all the possibilities, I want to be able to do it no matter where.

Comment: But suprisingly adding just `float:left` seemed to work alright